# Given a list of coordinates check if 4 points make a line

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, computational-geometry

I was doing some preparation for coding interviews and I came across the following question:

> Given a list of coordinates "x y" return `True` if there exists a line containing at least 4 of the points (ints), otherwise return `False`.

The only solution I can think about is in \$O(n^2)\$. It consist of calculating the slope between every coordinate: Given that if \$\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2 –x_1} = \frac{y_3-y_2}{x_3-x_2}\$  then these three points are on the same line. I have been trying to think about a DP solution but haven't been able to think about one.

Here is the current code:

```
def points_in_lins(l):
    length = len(l)
    for i in range(0,length -1):
        gradients = {}
        for j in range(i+1, length):
            x1, y1 = l[i]
            x2, y2 = l[j]
            if x1 == x2:
               m = float("inf")
            else:
               m = float((y2 -y1) / (x2 - x1))
            if m in gradients:
                gradients[m] += 1
                if gradients[m] == 3:
                   return(True)
            else:
                gradients[m] = 1

    return(False)
```

Comment: Actually, @W.Chang's suggestion of computing the area can indeed work for four points: if the first three points are collinear, try the first two with the fourth.  The equation I use is `(x2-x1)*(y3-y1)-(x3-x1)*(y2-y1) == 0`

Comment: @Edward: Wouldn't that require 3 (or 4) nested loops, instead of the current 2?

Comment: @MartinR: Yes, I believe it would.  Whether that's faster or slower would depend on whether traversals are more or less expensive than the mathematical operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach could be using the [Hough transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform). This does require that the points are in a bounded space, but would lead to an algorithm \$O(n)\$. This does not necessarily make it faster, but I think it will be significantly faster for large sets of points. It works this way:

- Parameterize the potential lines in the input space using a distance from origin and an angle (typically, the angle is that of the normal line that goes through the origin).
- Set up a "parameter space", a discretized space using distance and angle as its two axes. You need to choose a sampling here. Each bin in this space represents a potential line in the input space (or rather, a collection of lines, within a small range of angles and distances determined by the discretization of the parameter space).
- For each point in the set, add 1 to each bin in the parameter space that represents a line going through this point. There is an infinite number of potential lines going through one point. These lines form a sinusoid in the parameter space, and it is quick to compute the set of bins covered by this sinusoid.
- Each bin in the parameter space that has a value of 4 (or larger) represents the parameters of a line that covers 4 (or more) of the points. However, due to rounding of the parameters, it is possible these points are actually not collinear. To disambiguate, visit each point and determine which ones contributed to the bin in question, then verify they actually form a straight line.

Under a worst case scenario, all points contribute to the same bin, but are not actually on the same line. However, if this happens, the discretization of the parameter space was chosen incorrectly.

Note that this algorithm was invented to detect straight lines in an image, meaning that all input points have discrete coordinates. However, this is not a necessary requirement to apply the algorithm.

Comment: Should that step say "Parameterize *points*" instead of lines?

Comment: @Edward: no, lines in space are parameterized. Points belong to lines, for each point you have an infinite set of possible lines that go through it, you accumulate these possible lines. If one line is possible according to multiple points, than those points sit on the same line.

Comment: What I mean is that the algorithm begins with *points*.  When you say lines, I am guessing you mean the line through each arbitrarily chosen pair of points.  Correct?

Comment: Yes, lines are imaginary -- each point has an infinite number of possible lines going through it. All of those lines are accumulated in the transform space.

Comment: @Edward: I rewrote the explanation a little bit. Is it clearer now?

Answer (score 3):

#### General remarks

> ```
> def points_in_lins(l):
> ```

The function and argument name can be improved. `l` is too short and does
not indicate at all that this is a list of points, and `points_in_lins`
(perhaps you meant `points_in_line`?) does not indicate that the function
looks for *four* points in a line.

`gradients` is in fact a dictionary counting *slopes.*

Iterating over all pairs of points can be simplified with
`enumerate()` and slices:

```
for idx, (x1, y1) in enumerate(l):
    gradients = {}
    for (x2, y2) in l[idx + 1:]:
```

The “set or increment” for `gradients` can be simplified with 
[`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) or a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
gradients = Counter()

# ...

gradients[m] += 1
if gradients[m] == 3:
    return True
```

The parentheses in `return(True)` and `return(False)` are not necessary:

```
return False
```

#### The math

Computing the slope as the quotient

```
m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
```

requires a separate check for a zero denominator, but is problematic
for another reason: *Rounding errors* can occur. As an example,

```
points_in_lins([(0, 300000000000000000), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)])
```

evaluates to `True`: The slopes from the first point to the
other three points all evaluate to the same floating point number.

A possible fix is to compare the “directions” , i.e. the (2-dimensional)
vectors between the two points, normalized in a way such that
two vectors pointing in the same (or opposite direction) are
considered equal.

If all coordinates are integers, then it is best to stick with pure
integer calculations. Normalizing the connecting vector can be
achieved by division by the greatest common divisor of the x- and
y-component, and possibly mirroring it.

#### Putting it together

```
from math import gcd
from collections import Counter


def four_points_in_line(points):
    for idx, (x1, y1) in enumerate(points):
        direction_counts = Counter()
        for (x2, y2) in points[idx + 1:]:
            # Compute normalized direction from (x1, y1) to (x2, y2):
            delta_x, delta_y = x2 - x1, y2 - y1
            g = gcd(delta_x, delta_y)
            delta_x, delta_y = delta_x // g, delta_y // g
            if delta_x < 0 or (delta_x == 0 and delta_y < 0):
                 delta_x, delta_y = -delta_x, -delta_y
            # Three identical directions from (x1, y1) means 4 collinear points:
            direction_counts[(delta_x, delta_y)] += 1
            if direction_counts[(delta_x, delta_y)] == 3:
                return True
    return False
```

It is still a \$ O(n^2) \$ algorithm, but more robust against
rounding and division by zero errors.

If the points are not guaranteed to be *distinct* then  identical points need have to be treated separately.

Comment: An even better way of iterating through all pairs would be [`itertools.combinations(…, 2)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

Comment: @200_success: I thought about that, but could not figure out how to reset/initialize `gradients` for each value of the first point.

Comment: Some remarks: `gcd` is found in `fractions`. While this ok with slicing I dislike `idx` running till the end when using `idx+1` lateron. The special handling for identical points may be done by avoiding the divison by zero and counting gcd==0 an 'special direction' and then checking for `direction_counts[direction] + (direction_counts[0] if direction else 0) == 3` (and avoiding

Comment: @stefan: As of Python 3.5, [`fractions.gcd()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.gcd)  is deprecated in favor of [`math.gcd()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.gcd). – *I* would prefer not to generate pairs of identical points in the first place instead of adding special code later to handle that situation.

Comment: I missed the introduction of `math.gcd()`, thanks. However `math.gcd()` differs from `fractions.gcd()`, it gives positive integers only. So your direction will not be normalized in terms of denominator sign. btw, my suggestion for handling of identical points is incomplete. better to count them in a dedicated variable and compare to `3 - identical_points`. What I missed was to check `direction_counts.most_common()[0][1]` with new identical points.

Comment: @stefan: You are right, thanks. It could be that I did my first test with fractions.gcd. Hopefully OK now.

Comment: Op has never specified whether there can be indistinguishable pairs in the sets (Pᵢ==Pj, i≠j).

Comment: @bipll:  Identical points would be a problem in OP's code as well. That's why I added the final remark.

Comment: Oh,  sorry, I somehow missed it. :-\